# Wicket - getting body of markup element

Tags: java, wicket

Assuming I have markup that looks like this :

```
<span wicket:id="text">Some text that I'd like to read</span>
```

Is it possible to get the content of the body of the tag somewhere, or is it irremediably stripped by wicket?

**Edit :**
My intent is to implement some kind of simple CMS. Users need to be able to enter LaTeX formulas, in the form of `tex>a^2</tex>` that I would then render with a RenderedDynamicImageResource. Other tags need to be interpreted in a similar way. I envisioned to do it in two steps with a `Panel` like this :

```
public class LightweightMarkupPanel extends Panel implements IComponentResolver {
    public LightweightMarkupPanel ( String id ) {
        super( id );
    }

    @Override
    public MarkupStream getAssociatedMarkupStream( boolean throwException ) {
        // Get the lightweight markup and convert it to wicket markup
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean resolve( MarkupContainer container, MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag tag ) {
        // AutoAdd components as needed
        ...
    }
}
```

I've been struggling with this problem for a while, so maybe I'm searching in the wrong direction.

Comment: Get the content where?  Do you want the "Some text that I'd like to read" to stay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MarkupStream` object of the Component contains the raw HTML body.
You can retrieve it using the markupStream.get().toString() method like this:

```
// <span wicket:id="message">message will be here</span>
add(new Label("message", "If you see this message ..."){
     @Override
     protected void onComponentTagBody(
         MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag openTag) {
         markupStream.get(); // "message will be here"
         super.onComponentTagBody(markupStream, openTag);
     }
});
```